# How to return the keys & values from two objects with different values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

How would I loop over two objects and *only* return a list of the keys & values that were different?

```
let list = [];

let previousObject = {
    key: 'key_1',
    name: 'Previous name',
    age: '30',
    location: '12345 Main St.',
    height: '77',
    weight: '215',
    ...
}

let newObject = {
    key: 'key_1',
    name: 'New name',
    age: '25',
    location: '54321 Main St.',
    height: '77',
    weight: '195',
    ...
}
```

I would like the list to return...

```
list = [{ name: 'New name', age: '25', location: '54321 Main St.' }]
```

Things to consider:

- The previousObject *might* contain more keys than the newObject
- Checking for these differences might happen more than once per user session

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Yimiprod/7ee176597fef230d1451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `list` is an array with only one object containing all the differences. To get that object, you can do this:

```js
let list = [];

let previousObject = {
    key: 'key_1',
    name: 'Previous name',
    age: '30',
    location: '12345 Main St.',
    height: '77',
    weight: '215',
}

let newObject = {
    key: 'key_1',
    name: 'New name',
    age: '25',
    location: '54321 Main St.',
    height: '77',
    weight: '195',
}

let diff = {}

for (const key in newObject) {
  if (previousObject[key] != newObject[key]) {
    diff[key] = newObject[key]
  } 
}

console.log(diff)
```

Comment: This works like a charm! I knew the solution was simple but for some reason I was getting confused with for loops :)